# Send Message with C# over Telegram with TLSharp

Tags: c#, telegram

I am trying to send telegram message with C#. I found [this page useful;](http://www.sochix.ru/how-to-send-messages-to-telegram-from-c/) called TLSharp.

however, I cannot find the front person Id (userId) by using these codes:

```
var userByPhoneId = await client.ImportContactByPhoneNumber("791812312323"); //import by phone

var userByUserNameId = await await client.ImportByUserName("userName"); //import by username
```

both  `ImportContactByPhoneNumber` and `ImportByUserName` methods are unknown.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Agha Sharif,
Import By Username is obsolete. try this code:

```
var found = await client.SearchUserAsync("username", 1);
        var u = found.users.lists.OfType<TLUser>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (u != null)
        {
            await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerUser() {user_id = u.id, access_hash = (long)u.access_hash  }, "Hi there!");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download last version in [here](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp)

You need to do some configuration first.

Create a [developer account](https://my.telegram.org/auth) in Telegram.
Goto [API development tools](https://my.telegram.org/auth?to=apps) and copy API_ID and API_HASH from your account. You'll need it later.

and this is how to use it :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using TeleSharp.TL;
using TLSharp.Core;




namespace t
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        TelegramClient client;
        int api_id = your api_id ;
        string api_hash = "your api_hash ";
        string hash;


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TLSharp.Core.FileSessionStore store = new TLSharp.Core.FileSessionStore();
            client = new TelegramClient(api_id, api_hash, store, "session");

        }

        private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //if your app is not autenticated by telegram this code will send  request to add a new device then telegram will sent you a Autenticatin code
            await client.ConnectAsync();
            hash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync("your Number in global format example : 98916*******");

        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //if your app is not autenticated by telegram and you have sent request to telegram, this code will add new device using autenticatin code that telegram sent to you
            var code = txtAutCode.Text;  // this is a TextBox that you must insert the code that Telegram sent to you
            var user = await client.MakeAuthAsync("your Number in global format example : 98916*******", hash, code);
        }

        private async void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            await client.ConnectAsync();       

            // Here is the code that will add a new contact and send a test message
            TeleSharp.TL.Contacts.TLRequestImportContacts requestImportContacts = new TeleSharp.TL.Contacts.TLRequestImportContacts();
            requestImportContacts.Contacts = new TLVector<TLInputPhoneContact>();
            requestImportContacts.Contacts.Add(new TLInputPhoneContact()
            {
                Phone = "new Number in global format example : 98916*******",
                FirstName = "new Number's FirstName",
                LastName = "new Number's LastName"
            });
            var o = await client.SendRequestAsync<TeleSharp.TL.Contacts.TLImportedContacts>((TLMethod)requestImportContacts);
            var NewUserId = (o.Users.First() as TLUser).Id;
            var d = await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerUser() { UserId = NewUserId }, "test message text");



            //find recipient in contacts and send a message to it
            var result = await client.GetContactsAsync();           
            var user = result.Users
                .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(TLUser))
                .Cast<TLUser>()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Phone == "recipient Number in global format example : 98916*******");
            MessageBox.Show((user.LastName).ToString());

            //send message
            await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerUser() { UserId = user.Id }, "hi test message");
        }
    }
}




<Window x:Class="t.MainWindow"   
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:t"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="send Request" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="229,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Click="button_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="autenticate new device" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="229,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Click="button1_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="button2" Content="send Message" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="229,151,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Click="button2_Click" />

        <TextBox x:Name="txtAutCode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="229,108,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="123" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```